# NullPointException in Hive UDAF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I Write a hive UDAF, when using it in hive. It throws NullPointException
The code and entire task logs is pasted on github gist --> https://gist.github.com/hellojinjie/6750572

Any idea why it throws NullPointException?

Or why it says :

`stderr logs
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Continuing ...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unbound variable: GenericUDAFCdnBytesLoaded$GenericUDAFCdnBytesLoadedEvaluator0
Continuing ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDAT need to extends AbstractGenericUDAFResolver

see https://github.com/hellojinjie/hive-function/blob/d321281f67c357f50e8d3f98252c65682049da06/src/main/java/shaman/hive/udf/GenericUDAFCdnBytesLoaded.java